# Filter list in eclipse debugger (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to filter a List in the debugger of eclipse (Java)?

i.e. Say we have an ArrayList and a Test Class with attribute size. I'd like to look at all entries with size = 2, then maybe size > 4 etc. quite flexibly. How would I do that?

Of course I could "programm" it outside the debugger, but I then would loose the desired flexiblity...

Comment: Provide a "toString"-expression which uses the `list.stream().filter(e->e.size==2).collect(Collections.toList())` approach? (for Java 8)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Thx, this was my first idea as well. But unfortunately all my lists seem to "loose the generic" within the debugger. List is of type ArrayList<E> instead of ArrayList<Test>. Casting in the detail formatter does not solve the issue: i.e. "get(0)" works great. ((Test) get(0)).getSize() does not. Error: Detail formatter error: Test cannot be resolved to a type. Any hint?

Comment: Use full name - com.bigcompany.Test instead of Test.

Comment: Is this working for you? No success here. ((com.bigcompany.Test) get(0)).getSize() -> Detail formatter error: Test cannot be resolved to a type bigcompany cannot be resolved to a type. -> doublechecked the right path of Test with "Test.class.getCanonicalName()" returning "com.bigcompany.Test". Seems to be ok though?